# How to stop keypressing While loop with keypress

Tags: java

so I'm here with a small problem. I'm making a program, which after pressing a predefined button is going to spam pressing "W" (for now) until I will press that button again. I'm using JNativeHook library to check the keypress, but when my program starts spamming W's everywhere, this library stops checking pressed buttons. How can I solve this problem? There are some fragments of my program:

```
public class Buttons implements NativeKeyListener {

    private ButtonsAction buttonsAction = new ButtonsAction();

    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));

        if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_K) {
            buttonsAction.startBot();
        }
    }

    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void start() {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());
        logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        }
        catch (NativeHookException ex) {
            System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");

            System.exit(1);
        }

        GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(new Buttons());
    }
}
```

```
public class ButtonsAction {

    private int state = 0;

    public void startBot() {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            while (state == 0) {
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
        } catch (AWTException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mre]. How and where are you calling `nativeKeyPressed()`?

Comment: [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), as a side effect, you might also like to take a look at [Atomic Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) and [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) in general

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're using the same thread to execute the bot. You'll need to use another thread.

Comment: I'm new to multithread, but while checking on which thread everything works, they are working on different threads. Checking keypresses is working on 28th thread and the ButtonsAction works on 29th thread.

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking at the call stack ?